# Advantage or non-advantage in Control Version?

Tags: version-control, architecture, software-design

Yesterday I had a doubt about
We all talk about Control Version in Software but I have some questions to do

**Scenario:**
I have a version 1.0 and I go to version 2.0 (imagine that I made lots of changes to the database at the second)
3 months later my client decides that the version 1.0 was better.
So, I have two options.

1) I undo to version 1.0 and I loose all the data and changes made to database at 2.0

2) I create version 3.0, equal to 1.0 but the database will be from version 2.0, saving all data registered but it will not display to the screen

I dont know If I am explaining the situation in the correct way, but is there any more options? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, those are really your options.  Version control is definitely one of those "settled issues" that aren't really up for debate anymore.  It is the right way to do things.